# mapping <up>, <down> to `comint-previous-input` and `comint-next-input`

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I'd like to map `<up>` and `<down>` to  `comint-previous-input` and `comint-next-input` respectively.

I have done this successfully for shell:

```
(eval-after-load "shell"
  '(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'comint-previous-input))
(eval-after-load "shell"
  '(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "<down>") 'comint-next-input))
```

How do I do this for `M-x run-haskell`?

I tried:

```
(eval-after-load "haskell"
  '(define-key inferior-haskell-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'comint-previous-input))
(eval-after-load "haskell"
  '(define-key inferior-haskell-mode-map (kbd "<down>") 'comint-next-input))
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: How did it not work? Was there any error? This is just a guess, but I think you need to change the `(eval-after-load "haskell" ....)` to `(eval-after-load "inf-haskell" ...)` because that is where `inferior-haskell-mode-map` is defined. But without more information about what does not work, I cannot say for sure.

Comment: What @NickD said. Please clarify the question, for better help with answers.